# Spring 3 password encoding not working on save

Tags: spring, spring-security, password-encryption

I have the following:

```
   @Override
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsManager()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Bean
public MongoUserDetailsService userDetailsManager() {
    return new MongoUserDetailsService();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it seems to be working OK for checking the password on login.

Am I missing anything else to be able to store the password encrypted as well?

Comment: How are you storing the password? You likely need to use the password encoder to hash the password before saving.

Comment: @RobWinch exactly what I needed so a simple encoding of the password. Appologies for the very simple question but I thought that spring could also do a bit of magic when you specified that that field was the password and that you would eventually compare it using the bcrypt mechanism ... anyways it is fixed. thanks

Comment: If you used one of the provided implementations of UserDetailsManager it would automatically take care of this for you. However, since you provided the implementation you must encode the passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to encrypt the password programatically when I was storing it. Essentially:

```
new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(user.getPassword())
```